# Unable to read Pub/Sub messages from local emulator in Apache beam

Tags: docker, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to run a simple Apache Beam pipeline with the `DirectRunner` that reads from a Pub/Sub subscription and writes the messages to disk.

The pipeline works fine when I run it against GCP, however when I try to run it against my local Pub/Sub emulator, it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I am using a custom `Options` class that extends the `org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubOptions` class.

```java
public interface Options extends PubsubOptions {

  @Description("Pub/Sub subscription to read the input from")
  @Required
  ValueProvider<String> getInputSubscription();

  void setInputSubscription(ValueProvider<String> valueProvider);

}
```

The pipeline is quite simple

```java
pipeline
        .apply("Read Pub/Sub Messages", PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
        .fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()))

        .apply("Add a fixed window", Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(WINDOW_SIZE))))

        .apply("Convert Pub/Sub To String", new PubSubMessageToString())

        .apply("Write Pub/Sub messages to local disk", new WriteOneFilePerWindow());
```

The pipeline is executed with the following options

```sh
mvn compile exec:java \
-Dexec.mainClass=DefaultPipeline \
-Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false \
-Dexec.args=" \
--project=my-project \
--inputSubscription=projects/my-project/subscriptions/my-subscription \
--pubsubRootUrl=http://127.0.0.1:8681 \
--runner=DirectRunner"
```

I am using [this](https://github.com/marcelcorso/gcloud-pubsub-emulator) Pub/Sub emulator docker image and executing it with the following command:

```sh
docker run --rm -ti -p 8681:8681 -e PUBSUB_PROJECT1=my-project,topic:my-subscription marcelcorso/gcloud-pubsub-emulator:latest
```

Is there more configuration required to make this work?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the analogous `mvn` command you use when running the pipeline against GCP? Is it just that pubsubRootUrl=http://127.0.0.1:8681 isn't provided as an argument?

Comment: Yes its the same without the pubsubRootUrl=127.0.0.1:8681 argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that an Apache Beam pipeline is unable to read from a local Pub/Sub emulator if you have `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable set.

Once I removed this environment variable which was pointing to a GCP service account, the pipeline worked seamlessly with the local Pub/Sub emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot the local emulator by issuing manual HTTP requests to it (via curl), like so:

```
$ curl -d '{"messages": [{"data": "c3Vwc3VwCg=="}]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8681/v1/projects/my-project/topics/topic:publish
{
  "messageIds": ["5"]
}
$ 

$ curl -d '{"returnImmediately":true, "maxMessages":1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8681/v1/projects/my-project/subscriptions/my-subscription:pull
{
  "receivedMessages": [{
    "ackId": "projects/my-project/subscriptions/my-subscription:9",
    "message": {
      "data": "c3Vwc3VwCg==",
      "messageId": "5",
      "publishTime": "2019-04-30T17:26:09Z"
    }
  }]
}
$
```

Or by pointing the gcloud command-line tool at it:

```
$ CLOUDSDK_API_ENDPOINT_OVERRIDES_PUBSUB=localhost:8681 gcloud pubsub topics list
```

Also, note that when the emulator comes up, it creates the topic and subscription from scratch, so there are no messages on them. If your pipeline expects to immediately pull messages on the subscription, that would explain why it seems “stuck”. Note that when you run the pipeline at GCP, the topic and subscription you use there may already have messages on them.

Comment: I have a small app that is periodically publishing events to the local Pub / Sub emulator so there are plenty of messages when I pull them using the curl commands.